# Show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{k}z^{n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients

Show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{k}z^{n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}$ where $|z|<1$ and $k \geq 0$.

I know

The right hand side:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}} & = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}n(n-1)...(n-k+1)z^{n-k} \\
 \\
& = \sum_{n'=0}^{\infty}(n'+k)(n'+k-1)\ldots (n'+1)z^{n'} \ \text{let} \ n' = n-k
\end{align*}

The left hand side:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{k}z^{n}=\frac{(n+k)(n+k-1)\ldots (n+1)}{k!}z^{n}$$

There is a $k!$ in the denominator. I stuck here.

Comment: No, that's not the right hand side. How did you get that equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note

$$\binom{n+k}{k} = \binom{n+k}{(n+k) - k} = \binom{n+k}{n}.$$

Now

\begin{align}\binom{n+k}{n} &= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (n+k)}{n!}\\
&= (-1)^n\frac{(-k-1)(-k-2)\cdots (-n-k)}{n!}\\
&= (-1)^n \frac{(-k-1)((-k-1)-1)\cdots ((-k-1)-n+1))}{n!}\\
&= (-1)^n\binom{-k-1}{n},
\end{align}

and hence

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k}z^n = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \binom{-k-1}{n}(-z)^n = (1 + z)^{-k-1}.$$